# 301 redirect (htaccess) with ID to a new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a question about a 301 redirect (htaccess); the URL: https://www.old-domain.de/key.php?id=0000&ap=ap_id should redirect to https://www.newdomain.de/key.php?id=0000&ap=ap_id

Some URLs redirected like this: 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=00
RewriteRule ^$ https://newdomain.de/page/ [R=301,L]

But with the key.php?id=0000&ap=ap_id it does not work. Anybody is able to help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you provide your code?

Comment: I tried this: 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=2547
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.newdomain.de/key.php?id=2547&ap=ap_id [R=301,L]

and:

Comment: and 2. try: 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.newdomain.de/?$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Please don’t post code like that in comments, that is hardly readable. Edit your question instead, and format the code https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Your RewriteRule still has to match the path of the requested URL, otherwise it won’t rewrite anything. `^$` matches on an empty path only, i.e. if you had requested `http://example.com/?id=1234`

Comment: Thank you for the advice, was my first post on this page.